# Simple Regex comprehension issue

Tags: python, sql, regex

I would like to filter an SQL file of the following format using Python 3.3 (source: wikipedia):

**INSERT INTO `pagelinks` VALUES (10,0,'Computer_accessibility'),(12,0,'-ism'),(12,0,'1848_Revolution'),(12,0,'1917_October_Revolution'),(12,0,'1919_United_States_anarchist_bombings')**

**INSERT INTO `pagelinks` VALUES (12,0,'Albert_Camus'),(12,0,'Albert_Libertad'),(12,0,'Albert_Meltzer'),(12,0,'Aleister_Crowley'),(12,0,'Alex_Comfort')**

So basically you have lines starting with an INSERT statement, followed by content tuples in parentheses who themselves are separated by commas. Each line ends with the last item's closing parenthesis. The regex will only be working on single lines at a time.

I want to extract the first integer (*10* or *12* in this example) and the *UTF-8* string, but only under the condition that the second integer be a 0 (zero). I used the group () feature for this with the following regex...

```
\((\d+),0,'(\S+)'
```

...trying various other combinations with slight modifications. I am able to get a collection of all integers as intended, but once I try to match the string part, the whole remaining line becomes the match of the second group.

So instead of

```
10 Computer_accessibility
12 -ism
```

I get

```
10 Computer_accessibility'),(12,0,'-ism'),(etc..
```

How do I tell the engine to stop at the closing *'* or *')* for each group item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` quantifier is greedy, meaning it'll consume as many characters as it possibly can. To make it non-greedy, append a question mark to it: `\((\d+),0,'(\S+?)'`.

Comment: Well that does it, you've already fixed it. It just occurred to me that \S might match the closing single quote itself, or does that count as whitespace? If not, does the non-greedy way mean it notices the closing ' and takes the first match, i.e. the content up to that point?

Comment: @Adrian `\s` matches all whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, newlines, …); `\S` matches everything that's not a whitespace character, so yes, it matches a single quote. The non-greedy quantifier will consume one character and then try to match the single quote; it'll continue consuming one more character until it can finally match the single quote. If it can't, the match as a whole will fail.